# Trying to use GDS to access Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Tom Walder's GDS PHP Library to access Google Datastore.

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

This is my latest attempt:

```
require_once 'src/GDS/Entity.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Gateway.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Mapper.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Schema.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Store.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Exception/Contention.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Exception/GQL.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Gateway/GoogleAPIClient.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Gateway/ProtoBuf.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Mapper/GoogleAPIClient.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Mapper/ProtoBuf.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Mapper/ProtoBufGQLParser.php';
require_once 'src/GDS/Property/Geopoint.php';

// Build a new entity
$obj_book = new GDS\Entity();
$obj_book->title = 'Romeo and Juliet';
$obj_book->author = 'William Shakespeare';
$obj_book->isbn = '1840224339';

// Write it to Datastore
$obj_store = new GDS\Store('Book');
$obj_store->upsert($obj_book);

$obj_store = new GDS\Store('Book');
foreach($obj_store->fetchAll() as $obj_book) {
    echo "Title: {$obj_book->title}, ISBN: {$obj_book->isbn} <br />", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which is producing this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not determine DATASET, please pass to GDS\Gateway\ProtoBuf::__construct()' in /var/www/html/src/GDS/Gateway/ProtoBuf.php:70 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/src/GDS/Store.php(81): GDS\Gateway\ProtoBuf->__construct() #1 /var/www/html/test.php(32): GDS\Store->__construct('Book') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/src/GDS/Gateway/ProtoBuf.php on line 70
```

I'm trying really hard to get this to work. If any of you could help me I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to run this script from the command line?

If you run it from a GAE "web" environment (like the local web server or live AppEngine) then the DATASET will be defined by the environment.

Can you confirm exactly how you are trying to use the library? Then I can give you pointers.

For now - try running your code in response to a web request (i.e. from http://localhost:8080/test.php - or whatever)

Comment: I have Tom's GDS installed in the /src/ folder on my web server. I'm using a LAMP stack with php. It's on a google compute instance actually.

Comment: Oh wait, are you Tom Walder?

Comment: Yes indeed! I'm the author

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am the author of the library.

If you are running on compute engine, you need to use the "JSON" Google Gateway.

There should be some samples on GitHub.

Comment: Nice to meet you :) Unfortunately I'm self-taught and I often get tripped up by small things. Once I get it I am able to do good things though. Could you point me to some example syntax for JSON?

Comment: https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds/blob/master/examples/simple/create_one.php#L13

Comment: Ok, I used your example and commented out so that the JSON gateway was showing but now I get this. I do have Google Client installed but I couldn't find a service.json in the package. There's a /service/datastore.php though. Fatal error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in /var/www/html/src/GDS/Gateway/GoogleAPIClient.php on line 87

Comment: You should probably think about using Composer - you will need the library from here - https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: I think I am going to give up. This is crazy hard to get working. Trying to thread a needle in the dark :(

Comment: That's a shame. Lots of people use it no problem. Have you used composer before?

Comment: Haha. It will make your life so much easier!

Comment: I know but I can't risk my business just to make life easier. It's kind of frustrating how so many things only offer composer to install now. Some of them offer autoload.php and I can use that :(

Comment: Actually, I take that back, composer makes my life A LOT HARDER and makes a few very clever people's lives a lot easier....